# How can I get "useState" to work properly when using event handlers for mouse events witin a React component?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a simple "wrapper" to make HTML elements "draggable".

The problem I am having is that the "useState" variable `draggable` is always false within the event handler `mouseMove`. The event handlers `mouseDown` and `mouseUp` seem to work fine, except the fact that `dragging` is not properly set to true.

What am I doing wrong? Every suggestion or hint is highly appreciated!!!

PS: `console.log('Dragging is set to true')` and `console.log('Dragging is set to false')` are working fine! As far as understand it, all events "fire" properly. It's just that `dragging` is always false within `mouseMove`.

```ts
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

interface Coordinate {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

const SimpleDraggableWrapper = (props: any) => {
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState<Coordinate | null>(null);
  const [dragging, setDragging] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const element = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const mouseDown = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    if (element.current) {
      setOffset({
        x: event.clientX - element.current.offsetLeft,
        y: event.clientY - element.current.offsetTop,
      });
      setDragging(true);
      console.log('Dragging set to true');
    }
  };

  const mouseUp = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    setDragging(false);
    console.log('Dragging set to false');
  };

  const mouseMove = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    console.log(dragging);
    if (dragging && element.current && offset) {
      element.current.style.left = `${event.clientX - offset.x}px`;
      element.current.style.top = `${event.clientY - offset.y}px`;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={element} onMouseDown={mouseDown}>
      {React.cloneElement(props.children)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SimpleDraggableWrapper;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem related to stale closures.

To know more check: https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/.

You can resolve this issue in two different ways:

1. **Add dragging in the useEffect dependency array**

```
    useEffect(() => {
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
      };
    }, []);
    useEffect(() => {
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
      };
    }, [dragging]);
```

2. **Wrap mouseMove in a useCallback hook with dragging in its dependency array and then add mouseMouve function in the useEffect dependency array**

```
    const mouseMove = useCallback((event: MouseEvent) => {
      console.log(dragging);
      if (dragging && element.current && offset) {
        element.current.style.left = `${event.clientX - offset.x}px`;
        element.current.style.top = `${event.clientY - offset.y}px`;
      }
    }, [dragging]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
      };
    }, []);
    useEffect(() => {
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
      };
    }, [mouseMove]);
```